# Add-in rejected for version number overrides and wrong resolution of the icon

Tags: office-js, office-store

I received the following validation errors while trying to publish my add-in to the store:

1. Version Number Overrides
   The mailbox version in the Version Overrides elements in the manifest must have a version number greater than or equal to the mailbox version in the Requirements section of the manifest. Please update the manifest and re-submit your offer.

2.Incorrect Referenced High-Resolution Icon Size
The icon referenced in the offer manifest or package must be 128 x 128 pixels with a 1:1 ratio.

The current resolution 32 * 32 pixels.

Please update the URL or the referenced file and re-submit your offer.

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>d840334c-bca6-459f-8ce0-00016e3f4616</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CAT - Cognitive Automation Technologies</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Zepto-ai"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Zepto email tracking"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://user.zepto-ai.com/howto"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Icon.64x64"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                 <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Icon.64x64"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group> 
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.64x64" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon64.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Zepto-ai"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Track"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Icon.64x64"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                 <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Icon.64x64"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group> 
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.64x64" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon64.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/assets/probilly_icon80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookaddins.zepto-ai.com/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Zepto-ai"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Track"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

What am I doing wrong because I have put DefaultMinVersion = 1.5 also inside the elements of version override and the high resolution link is actually a link to 128x128 image.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 

1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Answer (score 0):

You should update the IconUrl to point to an icon with a resolution of 64x64 pixels instead of 32x32 as the documentation states that this is the recommended image size for Outlook add-ins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/iconurl).